# Creating CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, mvvm, winrt-xaml

Hello everyone I am new to XAML MVVM concepts  I know need I few concepts of CollectionViewSource I have a WinRT App with GridView I want to group every item by Profession  I created a ModelView how to translate to collectionView source I Searched in Google but no solution here goes a few part of code:

```
  <Page.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
                <Border  >

                    <Grid Background="DodgerBlue" Height="150" Width="200" Margin="0,-7,-7,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False">
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                            <StackPanel.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity=".25"/>
                            </StackPanel.Background>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Profession}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid x:Name="gridviewVariableSized" MaximumRowsOrColumns="4" Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>

        </Page.Resources>
 <Page.DataContext>
        <ModelView:PeopleCollection/>
    </Page.DataContext>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the CollectionViewSource, in your ViewModel call

```
var groupable = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.PeopleCollection);
```

(assuming Peoplecollection is an ObservableCollection or something similiar. Once you have this you can group using

```
groupable.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Country"));
```

Comment: Does this answer refer to the WinRT classes?